# Trouble finding area of triangle

Tags: java, geometry

I have a method that gets the area of a triangle, however it is returning 0.0.

```
public double getArea() {
    //Find the length of sides
    double side1 = p1.findLength(p2);
    double side2 = p2.findLength(p3);
    double side3 = p3.findLength(p1);

    //Get area
    double s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
    return Math.sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3));
}
```

My Point class with findLength(). This function works as intended in my testing:

```
public double findLength(Point another) {
    return Math.sqrt(((another.getX() - this.getX()) * (another.getX() - this.getX()) )+
            ((another.getY() - this.getY()) * (another.getY() - this.getY())));
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working.

Entire Point class:

```
/**
 * Created by wilson on 9/8/2014.
 */

import java.math.*;

public class Point {
    private double x, y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double findLength(Point another) {
        return Math.sqrt(((another.getX() - this.getX()) * (another.getX() - this.getX()) )+
                ((another.getY() - this.getY()) * (another.getY() - this.getY())));
    }
}
```

My Test Program:

```
    Point p1 = new Point(0,0);
    Point p2 = new Point(3,3);
    Point p3 = new Point(-3,-3);
    Triangle2D t1 = new Triangle2D(p1, p2, p3);

    System.out.println("Area of triangle: " + t1.getArea());
```

Comment: Probably side1, side2, or side3 are 0. Did you try printing out their values after you assign them from findLength?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but [`Math.hypot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot-double-double-) would be very useful in your `findLength` function.

Comment: What are the types of `Point` x and y?  Are they doubles?

Comment: It works for me, if I set up the `Point` class suitably.  The error is probably somewhere else.  Perhaps you need to post more of the program.

Comment: I did check that side1, side2, and side3 are not 0. x & y in Point are doubles.

Comment: Added some more code.

Comment: You've given it three points that are all on the same line.  0 is the correct result.  Try changing `p3` to `new Point(-3,3)` and see if that works.

Comment: Wow. *facepalm* Sorry. Knew it had to be something stupid.

Comment: Any reason you're not using [`java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) and one of its `distance` methods? Or at least [`Math.hypot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot%28double,%20double%29)?

Comment: @ajb: Will you turn that comment into an answer?

Comment: Since you have a coordinate representation for your triangle, rather than using Heron's formula, I'd suggesting taking [half the cross product of (p3-p2) and (p1 - p2)](http://geomalgorithms.com/a01-_area.html).  Should be faster with no square roots.

Comment: @dbc's idea is a great one--just be aware that it could give you a negative area, so you have to use `Math.abs` if that isn't what you want.  (Sometimes it is.)

Answer (score 0):

The "triangle" you tested:

```
Point p1 = new Point(0,0);
Point p2 = new Point(3,3);
Point p3 = new Point(-3,-3);
```

actually consists of three points all on the same line (the line *x = y*). Therefore, 0 is the correct answer.  As far as I can tell, the code is correct.

Side note: I recommend using [`Math.hypot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot-double-double-), which computes sqrt(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup>) in the `findLength` function.  Besides making `findLength` easier to read, it has the advantage that it won't overflow if x or y is so large that x<sup>2</sup> or y<sup>2</sup> won't fit in a floating-point number.  (Not that it's likely you'll run into that problem, but why not do things right?)